# Можно ли вызвать MPI_Init() внутри своей функции?

Tags: c++, c, mpi

В сигнатуре указано `int MPI_Init( int* argc, char*** argv)`, что как бе намекает на то, что я данную функцию могу вызвать только внутри `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.

Comment: Так это... попробуйте?

Comment: Я бы с радостью. Просто непонятно что с аргументами делать... Откуда я их внутри своей функции возьму? И зачем эти аргументы функции `MPI_Init()` ? Она из них получает число процессов?

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что означают эти аргументы в `main`?

Comment: Да. Вы же в курсе что программы, использующие MPI, запускаются командой типа mpirun -n <число процессов> <другие параметры> <путь к исполняемому бинарю> ?

Comment: Не знал, но это и неважно. Скорее всего, `MPI_Init` как раз и разбирает только свои параметры, получая на вход вообще все. Так что в теории, отфильтровав параметры со входа в обычный массив строк, можно передать их откуда угодно. А можно просто передать параметры из `main` куда-то вглубь.

Comment: Я бы не стал. Ищите описание API для библиотеки MPI.

Comment: @0andriy есть неплохая лекция Воеводина (https://parallel.ru/vvv/mpi.html), однако там даже не указано явно что вся процедура проводится в main()

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать следующим образом: вызвать `MPI_Init()` внутри main, а внутри своей функции в начале вызвать `MPI_Barrier()`.

Comment: Не думаю, что это хорошая идея. Обратите внимание, в [man mpi_init](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mpi_init) написано -- `The MPI standard does not say what a program can do before an MPI_INIT or after an MPI_FINALIZE . In the MPICH implementation, you should do as little as possible. In particular, avoid anything that changes the external state of the program, such as opening files, reading standard input or writing to standard output.`. Т.о. лучше все же вызывать `MPI_Init()` в первой строке `main()`.

Comment: Ага, и? Почему отдельные процессы не могут независимо вызвать функцию и внутри неё синхронизироваться барьером?

Comment: Относительно IO: можно поручить эту работу нулевому процессу.

Comment: @avp, ну и тогда становится полностью непонятно зачем нужен MPI_Init(). Я то, дурак, думал что он нужен как раз для того, чтобы безо всяких процессов сделать всё нужное в одном потоке.

Comment: Причем тут вообще `Mpi_Barrier`? Это ведь синхронизация для всех процессов, которые запускаются в `Mpi_Init`/ Речь в вопросе все же о том, где вызывать именно `Mpi_Init`. Кстати, кроме запуска процессов, организации области связи между ними и проч., она может модифицировать свои аргументы (список аргументов командной строки).

Comment: @avp, Что именно вам непонятно во фразе "Можно сделать следующим образом: вызвать `MPI_Init()` внутри `main`" ? Если речь действительно о том, где её вызывать, то при чём тут IO ? Зачем вы подняли эту тему? Вам охота вести демагогию или вы наконец предъявите конструктивную критику (если она у вас имеется) ?

Comment: Затем, что ответ совершенно не стыкуется с вопросом. Видимо за 3 дня (Вы же автор и вопроса и ответа) "концепция изменилась"?

Comment: @avp, В вопросе спрашивается можно ли вызывать MPI_Init внутри своей функции. В ответе сказано что вместо этого можно вызвать MPI_Init в main, а внутри своей функции синхронизировать процессы барьером. Как я уже упоминал, однопоточную работу можно поручить нулевому процессу. Ткните пальцем в каком месте вам что-то не стыкуется.

Comment: Не стыкуются тем, что в вопросе нет ни слова о проблемах синхронизации процессов. Да и в комментариях к вопросу речь идет лишь о параметрах и их доступности в некой функции.

Comment: @avp Если мы вызываем MPI_Init() не в начале программы, то до его вызова ни о какой синхронизации речи идти не может -- другие MPI-вызовы не будут работать. Вы этого не знали? Проблема синхронизации может быть решена лишь если мы сделаем так, как предложено в ответе -- вызовем MPI_Init в начале, а затем сделаем вызов функции. Проблема есть, есть решение -- вы не хотите чтобы я упоминал об этом в ответе? Странное желание.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50676/discussion-between-avp-and-hunter).

Comment: @avp, если вы не в курсе, слова "Можно ли" как раз и предполагают о том, что необходимо перечислить нюансы, препятствующие данному действию (либо сказать что их нет). Т.о. если есть какие-то проблемы синхронизации в  случае, когда мы вызываем MPI_Init не сразу, то знание об этих проблемах автоматически означает ответ на вопрос (ибо проблемы есть, а решения нет). В таком случае вопрос просто не был бы задан.